# Export Mysql data to pdf using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I created a member registration webpage which allow user to feed his data (details like name, phone, address, particulars, etc.) there is a total of 25 such fields.
I use php and Mysql.
It is required that user should get acknowledgment along with details he entered. 
please let me know how to export that data to pdf file so that the user can print or save his data which he had entered.

Comment: I use TCPDF at work. It's really easy. You just use HTML and it converts it to a pdf.

Comment: you can just create an html page that displays all the informations and then let the user print it as he wants. If you want to create a pdf you can use a library like FPDF